# My father is French can I get French citizenship?

Tags: france, citizenship, australian-citizens

My father was born in France (to French parents) and has a French passport. I am a 26yo Australian citizen. Can I get French citizenship?

I have read a lot about it on various forums but was unable to get a conclusive answer as to whether it is possible.

I am looking for a conclusive answer, perhaps someone who knows someone who has done it or has done it themselves.

I am currently in France, learning French, and loving it.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you are French, and the reason is [your dad was French the day you were born](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F3068.xhtml) (at least it seems very likely it was the case).

As you are French, you can request a passport or national ID from your city. You will have to prove you are French by showing a birth certificate and a proof your dad was French at that time.

Comment: +1 but since his dad was born in France from French parents, it seems exceedingly unlikely that he hasn't been French all his life himself.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this site](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F3068.xhtml) you are French if

- one of your parent on your birth certificate is French when you were born
- one of your parent on your birth certificate becomes French while you are still a minor and unmarried (for example they get their citizenship later by naturalization). In this case you have to be a resident in France to get your parent's citizenship, or you have to be a resident in France for at least 5 years as a minor if you are living abroad at the moment. If you are allowed to get French nationality based on this or the previous criteria, then it doesn't matter if your parent loses French nationality later.
- you were born in France, and one of your parent is also born in France (doesn't need to have French nationality though)
- you were born in France and at least one of your parents was born in Algeria, before the 3rd July 1962
- you were adopted by a French national in France